# How to remove default "trusted" root CAs

Tags: fedora, certificates

I can't seem to find where the default list of trusted CA's are on my fedora (23) build. Every time I thought I got close I found a README warning me that the file I was looking at would get overwritten if the command `update-ca-trust` was ran. And this was verified by me when I was making java keystore edits to 
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.92-1.b14.fc23.x86_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts` (my deletions were added back in)

The README's did reference me to look: `/usr/share/pki/ca-trust-source/` and `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/` however both seem to be deadends, as every crt file I ran an openssl x509 to inspect on didn't list all the root ca's.

An example of one of the default "trusted" root CA's that I would like to remove:

```
Alias name: chinainternetnetworkinformationcenterevcertificatesroot
Creation date: Jul 5, 2016
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=China Internet Network Information Center EV Certificates Root, O=China Internet Network Information Center, C=CN
Issuer: CN=China Internet Network Information Center EV Certificates Root, O=China Internet Network Information Center, C=CN
Serial number: 489f0001
Valid from: Tue Aug 31 03:11:25 EDT 2010 until: Sat Aug 31 03:11:25 EDT 2030
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  55:5D:63:00:97:BD:6A:97:F5:67:AB:4B:FB:6E:63:15
     SHA1: 4F:99:AA:93:FB:2B:D1:37:26:A1:99:4A:CE:7F:F0:05:F2:93:5D:1E
     SHA256: 1C:01:C6:F4:DB:B2:FE:FC:22:55:8B:2B:CA:32:56:3F:49:84:4A:CF:C3:2B:7B:E4:B0:FF:59:9F:9E:8C:7A:F7
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3
```

Comment: In CentOS(6) which is _mostly_ like Fedora, with `ca-certificates.noarch 2015.2.4-65.0.1.el6_6` I have that cert in `/usr/share/pki/ca-trust-source/ca-bundle.trust.crt` at lines 4913-5000.

Comment: Remember that the files contain many certificates, while `openssl x509` will only show the first one found. You'd have to split the file to view all of them.

Comment: Thanks to both @dave_thompson_085 and @garethTheRed, I think I have the proper file tracked down `/usr/share/pki/ca-trust-source/ca-bundle.trust.crt`. I'm going to make my edits and I report back if they worked.

Comment: The [Ubuntu version of this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440580/how-does-one-remove-a-certificate-authoritys-certificate-from-a-system) has an answer for Debian-derived systems.  I'd be stunned if it was at all applicable to Fedora, but perhaps other readers may appreciate the link.